# Convert a string containing a special character to string array

Tags: c#

I had the string like in this format:
string test="123_456_7890";
I need to convert this string into a string array like this:

```
string [] arr={"123","456","7890"};
```

Any help will be appreaciated.

Thanks
Sabbu

Comment: string.Split do all the things that you are requesting (with just one line of code). Perhaps you should try to do some research before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] arr = test.Split('_');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
string[] arr = test.Split('_');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the string functions to split it.
String[] arr = test.split(new char[]{'_'}).ToArray();

Comment: Split returns an string array.You do not need to call ToArray again.